# How can I display a numeric value on a website that corresponds with scroll distance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking to make a webpage with the same concept as [enter link description here](http://joshworth.com/dev/pixelspace/pixelspace_solarsystem.html) that displays relative distance between planets. I can't tell if this is a premade jquery plugin or custom built. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need mainly two things:

1. You need window.scrollY to get your current scroll. Note that Y is for vertical. If you want horizontal like them, use scrollX.
2. You need to add an event listener so you refresh the values when scrolling. The easiest way: window.onscroll

Then, it's up to you how to implement it, but something along these lines:

```js
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var px = document.getElementById('px');
      px.innerText = window.scrollY;
    }
```

```css
    main {
      height: 5000px;
    }
    #counter {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 2em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="counter">
    You are <span id="px">0</span>px down!
  </div>
  <main>
    Keep scrolling down!
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this libraries ;

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

and

https://magic.io/

Look for examples, you can do lots of things with them.

Comment: magic io demo : http://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/EajxXx  and a web site made with skrollr http://naveen.io/material/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for window 'scroll' change event.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(event){
  console.log(window.scrollY); // for vertical scrolling
  console.log(window.scrollX); // for horizontal scrolling
})
```